# Inserting a Zero instead of NULL while performing LEFT OUTER JOIN in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to insert a zero instead of NULL while performing LEFT OUTER JOIN on two tables?

Suppose I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uID from Class) T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT pID from University) T2
ON T1.uID = T2.pID
CASE WHEN T1.uID IS NULL
    THEN 0
ELSE T1.uID
END AS uID`
```

Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN a.fieldname IS NULL 
       THEN 0
       ELSE a.fieldname
END AS fieldname
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uID from Class) T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT pID from University) T2
ON T1.uID = T2.pID
CASE WHEN T1.uID IS NULL
THEN 0
ELSE T1.uID
END AS uID`
Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If you wanna join the T1.UID as 0 when it is null, use below:
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN uID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE uID END AS uID  from Class) T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pID from University) T2 
ON T1.uID = T2.pID `

Answer (score 17):

use `ISNULL(field, 0)` this will insert zero if the field is NULL

Comment: For MySQL you mean `ifnull()` instead of `isnull()` =)

Answer (score 5):

something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ifnull(uID,0) as uID from Class) T1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT ifnull(pID,0) as pID from University) T2
   ON T1.uID = T2.pID
```